# How do I find a specific symbol or character in Word using c#?

Tags: c#, replace, ms-word

I have a tool that formats documents and replaces page breaks in the following manner:

```
object findText = "^012";
object replaceText = "";
questionRange.Find.Execute(ref findText,
true, true, true, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceText, Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

This code works. I'm now trying to add an additional code block to find and replace a British pound symbol("£") with an inequality symbol ("≤"):

```
object findSymbol = Convert.ToChar(0x00A3);
object replaceSymbol = Convert.ToChar(0x2264);
questionRange.Find.Execute(ref findSymbol,
true, true, true, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceSymbol, Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

This code does not work. Anyone have any suggestions on how to find and replace that symbol?

Comment: What isn't working about it? any error?

Comment: Well, it's part of an addin installed into Word 2010, so I'm not seeing any errors...it's just not finding the symbol for some reason.

Comment: It would be almost impossible to help discover the exact problem.. all i could suggest is to look in the documentation for anything relating to special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing "findSymbol" and "replaceSymbol" with their respective unicode character encodings.

So it should look like this:

```
object findSymbol = "\u00A3";
object replaceSymbol = "\u2264";
questionRange.Find.Execute(ref findSymbol,
    true, true, true, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceSymbol, Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Less-than-or-equal-to: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2264/index.htm